# video tag doesnot working in zend framework 1.11

Tags: javascript, php, html, zend-framework

I am trying to take a picture by webcam and I have written codes which work fine but when I coppy them in my project with zend framework 1.11 it does not show any thing and even it does not ask about permission to access to webcam.
I have searched a lot but i am not even sure that is there any problem with zend version or not?

here is my code(i have found it in the internet and copy to one of my phtml files in my project)

```
            <!doctype html>
<style>
.layout1 {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.row1 {
  width: 100;
  position: relative;
  clear: both;
}
.cell1 {
  float: right;
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
}
.center1 {
  text-align: center;
}
#newImages {
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: -150px;
}
img.masked {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #babbbd;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #babbbd;
  margin: 10px auto 0;
}
#player {
  width: 320px;
  height: 240px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  border: 1px solid #babbbd;
}
canvas {
  width: 320px;
  height: 240px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  border: 1px solid #babbbd;
}
#capture-btn {
  width: 130px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#pick-image {
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 30px;
}
.btn.btn-primary {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
    touch-action: manipulation;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #337ab7;
    border-color: #2e6da4;
    </style>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Web app that takes pictures</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="layout">
  <div id="newImages"></div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">
      <video id="player" autoplay></video>
    </div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
      <canvas id="canvas" width="320px" height="240px"></canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="center">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="capture-btn">Capture</button>
  </div>
  <div id="pick-image"> 
    <label>Video is not supported. Pick an Image instead</label>
    <input type="file" accept="image/*" id="image-picker">
  </div>
</div>
<!--
<script src="script.js"></script>-->
</body>
</html>
    <script>
        const videoPlayer = document.querySelector("#player");
const canvasElement = document.querySelector("#canvas");
const captureButton = document.querySelector("#capture-btn");
const imagePicker = document.querySelector("#image-picker");
const imagePickerArea = document.querySelector("#pick-image");
const newImages = document.querySelector("#newImages");

// Image dimensions
const width = 320;
const height = 240;
let zIndex = 1;

const createImage = (src, alt, title, width, height, className) => {
  let newImg = document.createElement("img");

  if (src !== null) newImg.setAttribute("src", src);
  if (alt !== null) newImg.setAttribute("alt", alt);
  if (title !== null) newImg.setAttribute("title", title);
  if (width !== null) newImg.setAttribute("width", width);
  if (height !== null) newImg.setAttribute("height", height);
  if (className !== null) newImg.setAttribute("class", className);

  return newImg;
};

const startMedia = () => {
  if (!("mediaDevices" in navigator)) {
    navigator.mediaDevices = {};
  }

  if (!("getUserMedia" in navigator.mediaDevices)) {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia = constraints => {
      const getUserMedia =
        navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;

      if (!getUserMedia) {
        return Promise.reject(new Error("getUserMedia is not supported"));
      } else {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
          getUserMedia.call(navigator, constraints, resolve, reject)
        );
      }
    };
  }

  navigator.mediaDevices
    .getUserMedia({ video: true })
    .then(stream => {
      videoPlayer.srcObject = stream;
      videoPlayer.style.display = "block";
    })
    .catch(err => {
      imagePickerArea.style.display = "block";
    });
};

// Capture the image, save it and then paste it to the DOM
captureButton.addEventListener("click", event => {
  // Draw the image from the video player on the canvas
  canvasElement.style.display = "block";
  const context = canvasElement.getContext("2d");
  context.drawImage(videoPlayer, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  videoPlayer.srcObject.getVideoTracks().forEach(track => {
    // track.stop();
  });

  // Convert the data so it can be saved as a file
  let picture = canvasElement.toDataURL();

  // Save the file by posting it to the server
  fetch("./api/save_image.php", {
    method: "post",
    body: JSON.stringify({ data: picture })
  })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      if (data.success) {
        // Create the image and give it the CSS style with a random tilt
        //  and a z-index which gets bigger
        //  each time that an image is added to the div
        let newImage = createImage(
          data.path,
          "new image",
          "new image",
          width,
          height,
          "masked"
        );
        console.log(newImage);
        let tilt = -(20 + 60 * Math.random());
        newImage.style.transform = "rotate(" + tilt + "deg)";
        zIndex++;
        newImage.style.zIndex = zIndex;
        newImages.appendChild(newImage);
        canvasElement.classList.add("masked");
      }
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
});

window.addEventListener("load", event => startMedia());
</script>
```

many thanks

Comment: Zend is a _server-side_ framework, and as such doesn’t really have anything to do with this much. You have some sort of problem with your client-side code - so you need to start investigating, what that is. Start by checking the browser console, and by comparing your dynamically created output with your static version that worked.

Comment: Could you please show the code?

Comment: I have edited my post for the codes.  now i am using webcam.js instead (but my code is not completed yet).